# How to parse paymentMethod Object?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to list all of my user's payment methods. I am mainly trying to get the brand, expiration date, and last 4 digits of the credit card number.

I've tried multiple ways to parse the JSON payment method object being sent back from my server but I haven't been successful yet. This is what I did in the latest attempt I made.

In my server I get a list of all my user's payment methods and send back the raw data to my client using this function:

```
exports.listPaymentMethods = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const customerId = data.customer_id;
  const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
    customer: customerId,
    type: "card",
  });
  const pymtMethodData = paymentMethods.data;
  return {
    data: pymtMethodData,
  };
});
```

Here is how I'm calling the function from the client (it successfully prints the raw data):

```
func listPaymentMethods(customerID: String) {
    
    FirebaseReferenceManager.functions.httpsCallable("listPaymentMethods").call(["customer_id": customerID]) { (response, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("failed to list customer's payment methods: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        if let response = response?.data as? [String: Any] {
            let data = response["data"]
            print(data!) 
            self.parseJSON(data: data as! Data)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Here is the struct I made to store the payment method data:

```
struct PaymentMethod: Decodable {
    let brand: String
    let expMonth: Int
    let expYear: Int
    let last4: Int
}
```

I tried to use this function to parse the data but I was unsuccessful:

```
func parseJSON(data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(PaymentMethod.self, from: data)
        print(decodedData.brand)
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This is the raw data I get back from `print(data!)`

```
(
    {
    "billing_details" =         {
        address =             {
            city = "<null>";
            country = US;
            line1 = "<null>";
            line2 = "<null>";
            "postal_code" = 123456;
            state = "<null>";
        };
        email = "<null>";
        name = "<null>";
        phone = "<null>";
    };
    card =         {
        brand = visa;
        checks =             {
            "address_line1_check" = "<null>";
            "address_postal_code_check" = pass;
            "cvc_check" = pass;
        };
        country = US;
        "exp_month" = 12;
        "exp_year" = 2045;
        fingerprint = KKSbyUhUcKKSyto0;
        funding = credit;
        "generated_from" = "<null>";
        last4 = 4242;
        networks =             {
            available =                 (
                visa
            );
            preferred = "<null>";
        };
        "three_d_secure_usage" =             {
            supported = 1;
        };
        wallet = "<null>";
    };
    created = 1621941861;
    customer = "cus_JWaE2JEtbcI0JM";
    id = "pm_1IuyMzLVD5W50FFK2heBUTai";
    livemode = 0;
    metadata =         {
    };
    object = "payment_method";
    type = card;
}
```

)

I am basically trying to parse the JSON data so that I can have an array of PaymentMethod (the struct I added above) in order to refer to each individual piece of data from that PaymentMethod independently.

Anything to lead me in the right direction would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: What’s the error printed by catch? Have you tested your API call with 3rd party application like postman on anything, to confirm that returned data has all keys similar to payments model?

Comment: @TusharSharma It doesn't get that far. When I try to call the function `self.parseJSON(data: data as! Data)` the app crashes and the error says "could not cast value of type NSArray to NSData" I just added the function above so you see where it's called.

Comment: So there was a key in your JSON named `data`. It's not present in your struct `PaymentMethod`, what happened with it? What's the output of `print(error)` ?

Comment: `self.parseJSON(data: data as! Data)` fails? What's the full error message? I guess that can't convert as Data, because `data` isn't a `Data` instance. A Dictionary maybe?

Comment: @Larme there isn't a key in the JSON named `data`. That refers to the data being sent back from the server.

Comment: isn’t that should be response.data then?

Comment: @Larme Here is the full error message "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1f01114a0) to 'NSData' (0x1f01119c8)."

Comment: @TusharSharma I tried that and it says "cannot convert value of type '[String:Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Comment: I would suggest to run your API call in postman, and check the response structure, if you are able to solve from that it’s good, else you can show the response snippet here.

Comment: @TusharSharma in response to your first comment. When I call `print(data!)` it prints the raw data which has more keys than in my struct. But the ones in my struct are the only ones I need. Should I include all the keys even if I don't need them?

Comment: @TusharSharma I have added the response above

Comment: Your response is already parsed into Array & Dictionary. It's not JSON anymore, it's already Swift Objects. Add an init for your `PaymentMethod` with a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.data` has already been parsed into Swift objects, it's a `[[String: Any]]`. It's not a `Data` anymore, there is no need for `JSONDecoder`.

Add a custom init on `PaymentMethod`:

```
init?(paymentDict: [String: Any]) {
    guard let card = paymentDict["card"] as? [String: Any] else { 
        print("There is no \"card\" key or it's not a [String: Any] in: \(paymentDict)")
        return nil
    }
    guard let brand = card["brand"] as? String else {
        print("There is no \"brand\" key or it's not a String in: \(card)")
        return nil
    }
    guard let expMonth = card["expMonth"] as? Int else {
        print("There is no \"expMonth\" key or it's not a Int in: \(card)")
        return nil
    }
    guard let expYear = card["expYear"] as? Int else {
        print("There is no \"expYear\" key or it's not a Int in: \(card)")
        return nil
    }
    guard let last4 = card["last4"] as? Int else {
        print("There is no \"last4\" key or it's not a Int in: \(card)")
        return nil
    }
    self.brand = brand
    self.expMonth = expMonth
    self.expYear = expYear
    self.last4 = last4
}
```

Since `response.data` is an `Array` of `Dictionary` and not a `Dictionary`, and if you are interested in parsing the first one only:

```
if let response = response?.data as? [String: Any] {
    if let data = response["data"] {
        if let firstPaymentDictionary = data.first {
            if let payment = PaymentMethod(paymentDict: firstPaymentDictionary) {
                print("Payment found: \(payment)")
            } else {
                print("Invalid payment)
            }
        } else {
            print("No payment found in `\(data)`")
        }
    } else {
        print("No data in \(response)")
    }
}
```

Side note:
I added all the `else` in the `if let` AND explicit print in the `else` of the `guard let` to let you know what could be wrong and what they mean. Since a `if let`/`guard let` should be preferred over `!`.